# Ng show if the variable is a number

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to display an element only if a value is a number. How to do this? I tried :

- `ng-show='angular.isNumber(10)'`
- `ng-show='isNumber(10)'`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add to your scope:

```
$scope.isNumber = angular.isNumber;
```

and then use:

```
ng-show="isNumber(10)"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88wqe/

Comment: Does this works for string input? I dont think so. This just checks the type of the parameter you passing into

Answer (score 4):

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-show="isNumber(num)">
    AAA
</div>

function Ctrl($scope){
    $scope.num = '10';

    $scope.isNumber= function (n) {
      return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }
}
```

Here's a JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7RD47/

It uses the top answer from  [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric), which is a more complete way of validating numbers.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
ng-show='isNumeric(10)'
```

Comment: Please link to documentation for `isNumeric`, if it exists. I don't believe it's native to JS or to Angular, given discussions such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082.