# angular.isNumber not working in ng-if(Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

angular.isNumber  not working in ng-if  .
my condition is like this .in this i am checking zipcode / postal code whether it is less than 7 and it is numeric . first condition working absolutely fine ,the Problem is in second condition.

```
  <span ng-if = 'user.Zip.length < 7 && angular.isNumber(user.Zip)'>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324352/ng-show-if-the-variable-is-a-number

Comment: can it be used similarily in ng if which is included in ng-repeat ????

Comment: Can you try this and post the solution?.   Most probably it will work. The reason angular.isNumber is not working because while evaluating the praser unable to resolve what 'angular' is